# Calculating the max of a variable number of parameters

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure so I'm wondering if someone could explain to me where I'm going wrong. I'm solving some problems in [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com) to get familiar, and one of them is to calculate the max of a variable number of parameters, *without using Clojure's built-in max functions*. I'm supposed to fill in the blank:

```
(_ 1 8 3 4)
```

So that the result is 4.

To this end, I am trying to implement a function of variable arity. Since everything in a Lisp has to be recursive, my base case is when there's only one element, in which case the max is the element itself. Else, I compare the first and second element, and recursively call the function in the appropriate cases:

```
(fn max-of
    ; base case, only one element, return the element
    ([x] x)
    ; if more than one element...
    ([x & more]
        ; ...compare the first element and the second
        ; if the first element is bigger than the second
        ; drop the second element, else drop the first 
        (if (> x (first more)) (max-of (cons x (rest more)))
                               (max-of more))))
```

But this gives me:

```
user=>     ((fn max-of
#_=>         ([x] x)
#_=>         ([x & more]
#_=>             (if (> x (first more)) (max-of (cons x (rest more)))
#_=>                                    (max-of more))))
#_=>     1 8 3 4)
(8 3 4)
```

And I have no idea why this returns me a list as opposed to calling my function on said list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on the first recursive call you're passing a list as a single entity, see the difference between

`(max-of 8 3 4)` and `(max-of '(8 3 4))`

You might use `apply` to mitigate this problem:

`(apply max-of (cons x (rest more)))`